# knockout views transition in sammyjs

Tags: jquery, transition, sammy.js

I want to use jquery fade in-between views. I'm unsure how to do this in sammy.js. I thought of writing a function...

```
function showFade(_selector, newView, VM) {
    $(_selector).load(newView, function() {            
        $(newView).fadeIn('slow');
        ko.applyBindings(VM, $(_selector)[0]);
    });
```

then calling it:

```
app.get('#/newfile', function(){
  mainView.currView('landing');
  var _view = new newfileVM(mainView);
  showFade('#pagecontent', '/app/files/newfile.html', _view);
});
```

But this doesn't work (I didn't think it would, but just tried anyway).  I appreciate anyone help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me.  No one posted an answer so I'm answering this myself.

```
function showFade(_selector, newView, VM) {
    $(_selector).load(newView, function() {            
        $(newView).hide().fadeIn('slow');
        ko.applyBindings(VM, $(_selector)[0]);
    });
```